# Problema com animação de transição entre fragments

Tags: java, android

Estou trabalhando em um app que é composto por vários `fragments` e decidi colocar animações entre eles. Procurando, descobri que devo usar o comando `setCustomAnimations` para obter o resultado desejado, porém só consigo duas animações possíveis: fade-in e fade-out.

Procurando nas pastas da plataforma que estou usando (`android-19`, ou Android 4.4.2) vi que existem outras animações que não estão disponíveis no meu SDK estão presentes na pasta (`fragment_close_enter/exit`, `fragment_fade_enter/exit`, `fragment_open_enter/exit`).

Por que meu SDK não está reconhecendo-as? Esse é o código que estou usando para criar o `fragment`:

```
FragmentTransaction transFrag = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
transFrag.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
        android.R.animator.fade_out);
transFrag.addToBackStack(null);
transFrag.replace(R.id.container_login, login);
transFrag.commit();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por que você não cria suas próprias animações usando um xml com um objectAnimator?

Sete as animações assim:

```java
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.container_login, login, "login");
ft.commit();
```

Um exemplo da animação slide_in_left utilizando o objectAnimator:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-1280"
    android:valueTo="0" 
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Para a animação slide_out_right é só inverter os valores.
As duas animações(slide_in_left e slide_out_right) estão na pasta res/anim

Comment: Estava pensando nisso, mas não sei exatamente como "converter" de `anim` para `animator`, pois percebi que há uma diferença de sintaxe. Existe algum lugar que eu possa ler mais sobre isso?

Comment: Sim, o objectAnimator funciona a partir da API 11. Não sei onde vc pode ler para "converter" da framework antiga para a nova ou vice-versa. Se não encontrar, aconselho estudar as duas e entender o que faz o que em cada uma delas.

Comment: Entendi. Consegui inserir as animações que eu queria apenas corrigindo alguns errinhos, então não acho que precisarei converter as outras. Obrigado!